# To redirect a url from having specific string to aonther url in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have to redirect url in my site to single url. Means if any go to http://www.example.com/blog/photos/IMG_5867_2-tm.jpg, He should go to the particulate url i gave. e.g. ( http://www.example.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/common.png )

I have followed some answers in the previous question from Stackoverflow. But it is not working for me. I have tried like this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
Rewriterule ^blog/photos/(.*)$ exampe.com//blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/common.png$1 [r=301,nc]
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Is there anything wrong i have done. Please help and advance thanks.

Comment: May be it will help you: 

Rewriterule ^blog/photos/IMG_5867_2-tm.jpg(.*)$ http://www.example.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/common.png$1 [r=301,nc]

Comment: No it is not working. let me know you that i am using wordpress and it has its own .htaccess file. Let me added to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/

Rewriterule ^photos/.+$ wp-content/uploads/2015/08/common.png [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

If your .htaccess is placed in `/blog/` directory then `RewriteRule` will match URI pattern after `/blog/`